# Merging multiple rows into one row by Grouping and checking for non null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

I have data in this format. I want to merge multiple rows into one-row grouping by ID column. each row will have only one non null value and one non null value for each column when grouped by ID.

```
   [ID], [foo], [foo1], [foo2], [foo3], [foo4], [foo5]
    1,    data1,  null,    null,  null,    null,  null
    1,    null,   data2,    null,  null,    null,  null
    1,    null,  null,    data3,  null,    null,  null
    1,    null,  null,    null,  data4,    null,  null
    1,    null,  null,    null,  null,    data5,  null
    1,    null,  null,    null,  null,    null,  data6
    2,    data1,  null,    null,  null,    null,  null
    2,    null,  data2,    null,  null,    null,  null
    2,    null,  null,    data3,  null,    null,  null
    2,    null,  null,    null,  data4,    null,  null
    2,    null,  null,    null,  null,    data5,  null
    2,    null,  null,    null,  null,    null,  data6

Desired Output:
   [ID], [foo], [foo1], [foo2], [foo3], [foo4], [foo5]
   1,    data1,  data2,  data3, data4,   data5,  data6
   2,    data1,  data2,  data3, data4,  data5,  data6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aggregate functions `max` and `min` (as well as most others) will just ignore `null`s. You could group by the ID and query the max of the other columns, which would return the single non-`null` value this column has:

```
SELECT   id, MAX(foo), MAX(foo1), MAX(foo2), MAX(foo3), MAX(foo4), MAX(foo5)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you can use `max()`:

```
select id, max(foo) as foo, max(foo1) as foo1, . . . 
from t
group by id;
```

I should note that your original data structure is often produced by a query that is a bit awry.  Sometimes it is easier to fix the code that generates that result.